# How to plot linear histograms with Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, statistics

I have been reviewing how to plot a line histogram on data of my results. I have searched and only see how to plot in bar histogram, but I have not seen any construction of one of lines in latex. I also searched for TikZ but I can not find it.

Attached image of the type of histogram I want to do:
[image]

Any idea what I can use?

regards.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165735/simple-line-plot-with-date-on-x-axis or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267452/xy-plot-from-date-time-data-table-using-pgfplots

Comment: Are you sure that this type of diagram is called histogram? I would call it line chart with time/date x axis.