# How to draw a curve with the date on the abscissa?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization, csvsimple-13

I'm trying to trace with the library
{datavisualization}, the evolution of data depending on the current date.

I don't see how to get the date on the abscissa.

In the example below the date is in French format dd/mm/yyyy

```
% !TeX program =Xelatex+shell-escape
% !TeX encoding = utf8
%  !TeX spellcheck = fr 

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{plaquette.csv}
date,plaquettes
30/10/2023,1200000
02/10/2023,1229000
06/11/2023,980000
09/11/2023,570000
13/11/2023,308000
16/11/2023,259000
20/11/2023,117000
23/11/2023,65000
27/11/2023,21000
30/11/2023,39000
04/12/2023,590000
07/12/2023,1034000
11/12/2023,1960000
14/12/2023,1339000
18/12/2023,990000
02/01/2024,800000
06/01/2024,520000
12/01/2024,350000
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {datavisualization}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}

\begin{document}

\csvautotabular{plaquette.csv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple Line-Plot with date on x-axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165735/simple-line-plot-with-date-on-x-axis) From [doc](https://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#subsection.4.21.2) you should convert date to iso format.

Comment: yes, it's a good soluce. but is there a solution with datavisualization?

Comment: A starting point: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79252/pgfplots-data-time-format

Comment: In fact, I did not want to use pgfplots but only the tikz libraries but a priori, there is no solution with datavisualization